# Scrapy won't retrieve related searches

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to get data from Google SERPs. For the past few days, it won't catch related searches.
Any idea what changed and how to retrieve these searches ?
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: What have you tried (e.g. the code you are using)? What URLs are you using? What error codes?

Comment: Hi,I'm using a basic spider on urls like www.google.com/search?q=EXAMPLE. I dump then the result in a file where the related searches are not shown. It used to work until a few days/weeks ago.... In the request, I send a cookie and header to simulate a web browser and to pass the content page.

Comment: That's probably because Google has pretty sophisticated anti-bot mechanisms, and is probably returning an error and no search results when scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Zmike, that's my bet too but I'm looking for a workaround as some tools found online seem to get the data still now. So, I'm probably doing something wrong and that's what I'd like to understand, if anybody got the same trouble...